# In what region does cloud build execute its builds in?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

My organisation is based in the EU, and as such we have created all associated gcp-resources within the eu-region.

To speed up our builds, we maintain a dependency cache zip in a storage bucket, which we read from at the start of a build, and write to at the end of a build, depending on whether the dependencies have changed or not.

Now I wonder if we can expect builds to go faster, if we use a storage bucket located within a us-region, which brings me to my question:

In what region are cloud build builds executed in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check this, you can run this step:

```yaml
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone
```

For my project it's `projects/751286965207/zones/us-central1-f`

Not that is the same thing for all projects. In any case, a new feature is coming: [worker-pool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/builds/worker-pools/create)

The API is public but the project is in private preview. The principle is to have a pool of VM on which you can trigger Cloud Build jobs. Thanks to that, you will be able to define the region, but also, the connectivity to a private network (useful to deploy to a private GKE cluster for example) and to size your VM as you need. The counterpart, it should be more expensive.

Comment: Would you know where I can find the docs for that endpoint you are curling in the step?

Comment: Of, course, it's [metadata server, documented in the Compute Engine service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata) (and only there). Then, when you know well GCP, you know that metadata server are on every compute services (Cloud Run, Cloud Functions, Cloud Build, Datalow, dataproc,....) with some additions or limitations but you simple need to have a try on it and, most of the time, you get what you need!

Comment: Looks like the mentioned step doesn't work. I tried to specifically execute the build in the `europe-west1` region using this command: `gcloud builds submit --region=europe-west1`. But the step still prints `projects/[redacted]/zones/us-central1-f`, despite the fact that in on the [Build history](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=europe-west1) page the build is shown only if I select `europe-west1` in the `Region` dropdown.

Comment: Are you in a beta/alpha program? Did you were in previously?